# DevExpress gridview and combo box lost there css property

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, gridview, devexpress

My Question is when I use DevExpress control like gridview and combobox in a page under the update panel, when a page load a very first time all work perfect but when i make any event in control gridview and combo box under update panel lost there css property and look ugly but still works. How do i fix that problem? plz help!

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdateGridPanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <dx:ASPxGridView ID="Grid" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" Width="100%"
                        Visible="true" ClientInstanceName="Grid" EnableCallBacks="false" EnableRowsCache="false"
                        SettingsBehavior-ColumnResizeMode="Control">
                        <Styles>
                            <Header BackColor="#6C1502" ForeColor="White" CssClass="alertgridhears" Border-BorderColor="White"
                                Border-BorderWidth="2px">
                            </Header>
                            <AlternatingRow BackColor="#e6e6e6">
                            </AlternatingRow>
                            <Cell Wrap="True" Border-BorderColor="White" Border-BorderWidth="1.95px">
                            </Cell>
                        </Styles>
                        <SettingsPager PageSize="5">
                            <PageSizeItemSettings Visible="true" Items="5, 10, 20" />
                        </SettingsPager>
                        <SettingsLoadingPanel Mode="ShowAsPopup" />
                        <Settings HorizontalScrollBarMode="Auto" ShowGroupedColumns="true" ShowGroupPanel="true" />
                    </dx:ASPxGridView>
                    <dx:ASPxGridViewExporter ID="gridExpt" runat="server" GridViewID="Grid">
                    </dx:ASPxGridViewExporter>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you can also include some of your code.

Comment: i included that now thanks